# INavigationService as MainPage constructor argument

Tags: c#, unity-container, xamarin.forms, prism, uwp

I have the basic Prism/Unity/Xamarin Forms app from the Prism Templates.

If I change the following (add  parameter) it fails

```
public MainPage(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

container works but getting the navigation service this way causes MainPage to not be found.

Is there a better way for a ContentPage to get the navigation service so a button click can navigate to a new page?

I have also tried to register the navigation service from the OnInitialized as I have found in some samples and that is a compile error now.

Using following packages/versions:

- Prism.Unity.Forms 6.2.0.pre4
- Prism.Forms 6.1.0.pre4
- Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45
- Unity 4.0.1
- Windows 10 UWP

Comment: Could you post a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: The answer below helped me find the issue.  Thanks for your interest in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prism is a framework to help you create your apps by using [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel). If you go read up on MVVM and the practices used, you'll notice that code behind in your page should be kept to a minimal and the logic is moved to the viewmodel.

Applying this to your code, you should NOT add the `INavigationService` to your page, as navigation should be done from the viewmodel.

Now I hear you asking: "but how do I get from my click to the viewmodel?". That's done by using a command.

```
<Button Text="Navigate to speak page" Command="{Binding NavigateToSpeakPageCommand}" />
```

I suggest you have a look at the **documentation** and samples on the Prism repository:

- [Getting started with Prism on Xamarin forms](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/1-GettingStarted.md): step by step on your first page and navigation.
- https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld (not an official sample, but shows how to do navigation)
- https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms

Comment: You are correct, I was taking a shortcut to get this working quickly.  It was interesting that the code behind couldn't get the navigation service but the view model can.  Thanks for helping so quickly.

Comment: This reason you can't get the INavigationService in the View is to protect you from yourself. To prevent you from trying to do what you were just trying to do :)